# How to implement lazy loading for pivot table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, reactjs, lazy-loading

I am using Orb.js(plugin for pivot table), orb using reactjs for fast rendering but its very slow while using large data set. I need to achieve lazy loading on scroll function. Orb url : http://orbjs.net/

I am new to react I don't know how to achieve lazy loading. please give any idea or demo.

Comment: my fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/katherdx/fctcmyc8/1/show/